# Node.js steam trade bot, finding the items instanceid

Tags: javascript, node.js, steambot

Here is the basic code from one of the examples,

```
offers.on('receivedOfferChanged', function (offer, oldState) {
    logger.info(offer.partner.getSteam3RenderedID() +" Offer #" + offer.id + " changed: " + TradeOfferManager.getStateName(oldState) + " -> " + TradeOfferManager.getStateName(offer.state));

    // Alert us when we accept an offer
    if (offer.state == TradeOfferManager.ETradeOfferState.Accepted) {
        offer.getReceivedItems(function (err, items) {
            if (err) {
                logger.error("Couldn't get received items: " + err);
            } else {
                var names = items.map(function(item) {
                    return item.name;
                });
                // Log a comma-separated list of items received
                logger.info("Received: " + names.join(', '));



            }
        });
    }
});
```

What I am trying to do is whats similar to line 10 where he returns the name however I want to get the items instance id so that I may be able to place it into a array.

Any assistance would be well appreciated.

Comment: return item.id doesn't work?

Comment: @Molda does that return the instanceid?

Comment: Well, you can check what properties each item has by adding console.log(item); above return item.name;

Comment: @Molda very true, I'll go ahead and try it out and just search some more. Will leave an update when finished.

Answer (score 1):

This thread is now 1 years old but I still want to answer it for people who still don't have the answer.

As stated here: https://github.com/DoctorMcKay/node-steamcommunity/wiki/CEconItem
Img: http://prntscr.com/cx6qa9

You can get the InstanceID by asking it.

```
var instance_id = items.map(function(item) { 
      return item.instanceid; 
});
var instanceIDs = instance_id.join('/');
```